# ngx-webcam attribute for specific view and component angular 6

Tags: angular6

I am using ngx-webcam in my application to capture image using webcam. I have import library in app.module.ts and also on my view but it gives me this error
'webcam' is not a known element. If using webcam tag in app.component html it work good but i want to use it in separate view. This is my code

```
import {WebcamImage} from 'ngx-webcam';

export class CreateMemberComponent implements OnInit {
 private trigger: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

 // latest snapshot
 public webcamImage: WebcamImage = null;
public triggerSnapshot(): void {
    this.seconds = 3;
    this.trigger.next();
    this.seconds = null;
  }

  public handleImage(webcamImage: WebcamImage): void {
    console.log('received webcam image', webcamImage);
    this.webcamImage = webcamImage;
  }

  public get triggerObservable(): Observable<void> {
    return this.trigger.asObservable();
  }
```

here is my html code

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div style="text-align:center">
        <div>
          <p>{{seconds}}</p>
          <webcam [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)"></webcam>
          <br/>
          <button id="snapshotBtn" (click)="triggerSnapshot();">Take A Snapshot</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="snapshot" *ngIf="webcamImage">
        <h2>Nice one!</h2>
        <img [src]="webcamImage.imageAsDataUrl"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

Please see the attached image for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `WebcamModule` in your AppModule.

import {WebcamModule} from 'ngx-webcam';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    WebcamModule
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please see https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webcam#usage

Comment: Its working on app.component.html but not working on other pages

Comment: Are your other components under a lazy loaded module?

Comment: try importing it in the _members-profile.module.ts_ (assuming that this is lazy loaded in a router module)